# How to execute a large PHP Script?

Tags: php, timeout, execution

Well basically I may want to execute a script that may take as much as 1 hours as well.

What I really want to do is Send SMS to my users using a third party API. So its basically like I supply my script with an array of phone numbers and fire the method to send SMS.

However assuming it take 5 seconds to send 1 SMS and I want to send 1000 SMS which is roughly 1 - 2 hours. I can't use `set_time_limit()` because I am on shared host.

One way to do this is store numbers in a session and execute each SMS and use javascript to refresh that page until end. This way I need to keep my browser open and the execution will stop if my Internet Connection is disconnected.

So, Is there any better way to do this ?

Hope I am clear enough to explain what I want? I want to execute a large script that may take hours to execute without getting timeout.

Comment: Is talking to the API from a local computer where you can increase the time limit out of the question?

Comment: Do you have the ability to setup cron jobs on your shared host?

Comment: Yes, I do have access to cron jobs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your host lets you, cron jobs are the best solution. A cron job is basically a normal php script that is automatically run by the web server at a specific time interval. For your needs I would create a script that runs every 5 mins and processes your numbers in batches of 100 (obviously you'll want to tweak the time interval and batch size to suit). This will keep your server load down and prevent you getting in trouble with your hosting provider for hogging resources.

In order to track which batch your script should be processing, I would setup a track_batch table. These columns should give you a good indication of how to approach the problem:

id, date_run, start_record, end_record, final_run

Essentially:

- Check to see the date of the last
  batch run. If it isn't the current date
  (or whatever other identifier you choose to
  use) for the current batch, then
  proceed.
- If the last batch run *was* for the current date, then check the
  final_run column to see whether
  you've already finished processing
  all the numbers.
- If you still have numbers to process, use the start and end
  records in conjunction with MySQL's
  LIMIT to build the db query that your
  script will use to get the next
  batch.
- Process your numbers.
- Store all the info from this batch in the track_batch table.
- If the amount of numbers the query returns is ever less than the maximum
  batch size, you've reached the end
  and can set the final_run column to
  1.

Once you've got your script, you'll need to setup the cron job itself. Shared hosts are likely to have their own custom interfaces for doing this, so they are probably the best people to ask once you've got your script working.

Answer (score 21):

A PHP script executed from the command-line or from a shell script, cron job, etc. does not have a timeout.

For CLI-invoked scripts, even if you set the PHP script's timeout dynamically with the [`set_time_limit()`](http://php.net/set_time_limit) function, it has no effect.

Comment: please answer my question on : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98642/run-a-php-script-in-centos-and-time-and-timeout?noredirect=1#comment150287_98642

Answer (score 6):

PHP scripts running from the command line aren't affected by `max_execution_time` option.
So you don't have to worry at all.

Comment: And how do I run them as CLI on a shared host? I dont think I would have access to it.

Comment: See if you have a "cron" section in your control panel. That will let you run PHP scripts via the command line.

Answer (score 3):

It's not the best options to use `set_time_limit(0)`, because that'd means it'll run indefinitely even if you have a bug and your script enters an infinite loop.

Instead, if you estimate each SMS is going to take 5 seconds, use this approach:

```
while( $there_are_more_sms_to_be_sent ){
  set_time_limit(30); // enough spare time, just in case.

  // Do your sending, blah blah
}
```

That way, the time limit will be sequentially updated to 30 seconds. Of course you might have the infinite loop problem with that single `while`, but if you have other calls inside that `while` that limit will prevent *those* calls to be to blame.

Comment: so everytime it loops, is the counter reset?

Comment: That's right. I was assuming you were using a cronjob also. You should use it together with this tip, so you process, say, 100 messages each time but also you make sure you don't run out of time.

Comment: Are you sure you can stop cron jobs like this?

Comment: Stopping a process with set_time_limit() is never a good idea, because it may stop in the middle of something leaving inconsistencies. In this particular case, I assumed each SMS takes 5 seconds to be sent, so I suggested a generous 6x limit just in case something goes wrong, like an infinite loop or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You **can** or you **can't** use `set_time_limit()`?

If you can.. Use it:

```
<?php
// Runs forever and ever...
set_time_limit(-1);
?>
```

Comment: Hehe, I won't downvote because it's technically correct, but would you suggest he allow a script to run forever if he was *your* neighbour on a shared host?! :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to using JavaScript is to add the `Refresh` meta tag to your page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="2; url=http://yoururl/script.php&step=x" ?>
```

The two in `content="2; url=..` tells the browser to load the url 2 second after the page has loaded.

Comment: Thanks but, I already specified this in my question. I was looking for something to be done by Server Side. I also knew about CRONs but I thought there may be more ways to this

Comment: he's clearly asking how to .... PHP
technology workaround is not the best solution

Comment: I don't know why you think it necessary to react on a post almost 7 years old, but to reply: while using a cron or command line job is a very good solution to run large batch operations, splitting a job into small steps and executing them step by step is just as valid. Cron is nice where you can use it, but I successfully ran scripts that took more than 12 hours in the browser when I did not have shell access.

Answer (score 0):

IN THE CASE YOU CAN RUN CRON JOBS

I usually have a queue, a manager and workers. Unless you can call the sms api once at the time this model can help you, and you souldn't worry about timeouts since each worker will manage it selves.

I have something like:

```
<?php
// PSEUDO CODE
// grab pending from queue

// <for> {
// update to running
exec("/usr/bin/php /path/to/send.php {$id} > /dev/null &");
// }
```

and send.php will send each sms. Right now I have this running at a rate of 300/minute since is the max frequency that you can setup on a cron job